# Failed to add documents to Solr (django + haystack)

Tags: django, solr, indexing, django-haystack

I'm developing a simple search engine with Django + Haystack. I'm following these tutorial:

- http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#solr
  http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing_search_engines.html
- http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing_search_engines.html

At the time of indexing with

```
python manage.py rebuild_index
```

I receive this error:

```
Failed to add documents to Solr: No connection adapters were found for 'localhost:8983/solr/update/?commit=true'
```

I updated schema.xml, restarted solr server but the error remains. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem found. Definig the SearchIndex template I wrote:

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.user.get_full_name }}
{{ object.body }}
```

the problem was 'get_full_name'

with

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.user }}
{{ object.body }}
```

objects are indexed.

I suppose that User model hasn't a standar method "get_full_name".